# CPU percentage going high while enumerating root folder with NSDirectoryEnumerator

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am using NSDirectoryEnumerator for enumerating Folders, but the issue is CPU percentage is increasing more than 50% until the enumeration completes.Is there any way to handle this?

```
-(void)enumerateFolder:(NSString *)folder{
    
    NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:folder];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsDirectoryKey];
    
    NSInteger fileCount = 0;
    NSInteger folderCount = 0;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                         enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                         options:0
                                         errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                             // Handle the error.
                                             // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                             return YES;
                                         }];
    
    for (NSURL *url in enumerator)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
        if (! [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
            // handle error
        }
        else if (! [isDirectory boolValue]) {
            // No error and it’s not a directory; do something with the file
            fileCount++;
        }else if([isDirectory boolValue]){
            folderCount++;
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: you should probably run that in a background thread

Comment: Are you aware that this API scans the folder including **all** subfolders?

Comment: @Sulthan Its running in background thread only

Comment: @vardian Yes I am aware of it.

Comment: Well, the code asks your computer to do something; until that's done, it uses the CPU.  Not clear what kind of answer you want.  I suppose you could have your loop do a call to sleep() every time through, so it takes longer but uses less CPU...?  Is that what you're looking for?